# Gerrit: configure similarity index threshold (renamed file)

Tags: git, gerrit

I've made commit with big changes in a file and renamed file.

Git correctly shows me changes in the file:

```
git log --name-status
R050
```

and:

```
git show <commit-id>
similarity index 50%
```

But after pushing changes to Gerrit (code review):

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

Gerrit shows that one file is deleted and other added. It makes code review more difficult (you can't see only changes).

When I made commit with minor changes (for example `similarity index 98%`) or without renaming file, Gerrit shows changes correctly (as well as Git).

Question: How to change configure similarity index threshold (for renamed files) on Gerrit?

Comment: That's a bit curious, as the default threshold in Git itself *is* 50%. One would think if Gerrit has no tuning of its own, it would use this same default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Gerrit doesn't have any way to change similarity index threshold (as Git diff "-M" parameter does). I think the best way to workaround this issue is spliting your change in two changes, just rename in the first commit and then do the changes in the second one.